# show / hide multiple div using php, js, sql

Tags: javascript, php, sql, web, show-hide

i've have a problem when the content of the divs are showed.
I want to show divs using a idpost variable, but i dont know how to do this.
Now when i push show / hide button only works the first one div.
I would like to do this using a id var. The next code is the php file that i use in the index page with a include. It show me all the records of the database with an array.

```
<?php
    include "connections/con1.php";
                    mysql_select_db($database_con1, $con1);
                    $query_Recordset1 = "SELECT * FROM `general` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC LIMIT 9 ";
                    $result = mySQL_query ( $query_Recordset1 ) ; while ( $row_Recordset1 = mySQL_fetch_array ( $result ) ){

    $idpost=$row_Recordset1['idpost'];
    $msg_id=$row_Recordset1['timestamp'];
    $titulo=$row_Recordset1['titulopost'];
    $message=$row_Recordset1['contentpost'];
        if  (strlen($message) > 100) {
              $text = substr($message, 0,600);

    echo $idpost;

    echo '<div class="article" target="<?php $idpost; ?>">
        <div id="noticia"> 

                <h1>
                    '.$titulo.''." ".''.$msg_id.'
                </h1>'.'
                <h2 id="noticia_corta">
                     '.$text.''."...".'

                <input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" /> 
                <input type="button" id="hideDivButton" value="Hide Div" onclick="hideDiv()" />

            <h2 id="hiddenDiv" style="display:none;">
                <div   class="answer_list"> 
                            '.$message.'
                    <input type="button" name="answer" value="Show Div" onclick="showDiv()" /> 
                    <input type="button" id="hideDivButton" value="Hide Div" onclick="hideDiv()" />
                </div>
            </h2>

        </div>
    </div>';
 }
 } ?>
```

And this is the js function that do the action of the divs, but i dont know how to focus the problem

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    function showDiv() {
   document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('noticia_corta').style.display = "none";
}
function hideDiv() {
document.getElementById('hiddenDiv').style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById('noticia_corta').style.display = "block";
}
```

Thanks ^^

Comment: First of all stop using `MySQL functions` and convert to `mysqli` or `PDO`

Comment: i want to show records of my db, ordered by timestamp. For each one of this record, show only a limited size of words. Finally put a show /hide that show me the complete content of the record.

Comment: you missed a closing tag `</h2>` for id `noticia_corta`

Answer (score 0):

Use a **class** instead of an id. **Id's** are for **only 1 element** and classes are for multiple. In the HTML both divs should have the same class.

```
<div class="showHide">
```

In the Javascript code, instead of `getElementById()` use `getElementsByClassName()`